# How to write a mathematic equation in a table in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, mathematical-expressions

So I'm trying to write a mathematic equation in a table row in  Microsoft Access , like 
[image: mathematic equation]

but even if I copy it from Microsoft Word(for example), it automatically converts it to

> a^2+b^2=c^2

Any ideas ?

Comment: In a MS access table row

Comment: ^ is the squared operator in Access. What is the data format of your field and what are you trying to achieve? A calculation, or just text?

Comment: I am writing a maths exam program in c#. The questions and its answers are written in MS Access database(I have  QuestionsTable and AnswersTable)  . In c# i just display the rows from the MS database tables. So i want the mathematic equations In MS database  to be written in a proper form .I am writing a maths exam program in c#. The questions and its answers are written in MS Access database(I have  QuestionsTable and AnswersTable)  . In c# i just display the rows from the MS database tables. So i want the mathematic equations In MS database  to be written in a proper form .

Comment: The data format is text (Long Text)

Comment: You are going to need a rich-text control, and store HTML in the database. Your example can be simulated with the ² character, but anything more complicated won't work with plain text.